# Salesforce formula to calculate first day of next month

Tags: formula-field, validation-rule, date

I am creating validation rule which will fire if date of a custom field is greater that first day of next month.

I am using below formula in validation rule but it is not firing.

Custom field is EDate__c with date datatype

eg: if EDate__c is greater the October 1,2021 then validation should fire.

What is missing?

```
EDate__c > IF(
  MONTH( EDate__c ) = 12,
  DATE( YEAR( EDate__c), 12, 31 ),
  DATE( YEAR( EDate__c ), MONTH ( EDate__c ) + 1, 1 )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `EDate__c` too much in this validation rule.

You're performing some date manipulation on a given date, and then comparing it against that same date. The result will always be true, or always be false (depending on the comparison made), and things that never change no matter what input you give do not make for useful validation rules.

You want to be using two separate dates in this validation. One of them is `EDate__c`, the other is likely something like `TODAY()`.

You really only need to swap out `EDate__c` for `TODAY()` in your final call of the `MONTH()` function, but for ease of reading, I'd suggest replacing all but the first instance of `EDate__c`.

```
EDate__c > IF(
  MONTH(TODAY()) = 12,
  DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 12, 31 ),
  DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH (TODAY()) + 1, 1)
)
```

Given that TODAY() = 2021-09-07, this formula simplifies to
`EDate__c > 2021-10-01`, and the validation rule would complain if `EDate__c` were to be 2021-10-02 or later.

Comment: Thanks..It worked